# System keeps scanning hard drives when booting

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I've just bought one 2T hard drive and one 128G SSD. After installation, I found that every time when I boot my machine，the system will perform scanning, searching for hard drives that are not SSD. If I press `del` at that time to enter into BIOS, I will see no hard drives detected except the SSD. But once it finishes scanning, the operating system will started normally. I wonder what's wrong with my machine and how to disable the annoying scanning, thank you.

Comment: What precisely do you see on the screen while it's scanning?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Scanning Drives..............."

Comment: It doesn't say something like "RAID option ROM"?